# iterating with python while loops

Tags: python, iteration, edx

Write a while loop that sums the values 1 through end, inclusive. end is a variable that we define for you. So, for example, if we define end to be 6, your code should print out the result:

21
which is 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6.

Is anybody able to guide me through this, without spoiling it for me?

Comment: Welcome to the site. To get a proper answer you'll need to do some research yourself first. See [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things you can do. The "fast" way (a la the story about the young Gauss) recognizes that

```
sum(1:N) = N * (N + 1) / 2
```

But I doubt that is what is asked.

You need to create a loop (look at the `for` command) over a range (look at the `range` command), and in each iteration add the current value of the loop variable to the sum (which you initialize to zero before the start of the loop).

There - you should now be OK.

**EDIT** with a while loop, and still leaving you to do a little bit of work:

```
mySum = 0
i = 1;
while( <<< put some condition here >>> ):
  mySum = mySum + i
  <<<<< do something clever with i >>>>>
print <<<<< what do you think you should print here? >>>>>
```

Note that indentation is important in Python, and the `:` at the end of the `while` statement matters

Comment: I need to do this problem using a while loop.

Comment: Don't use `sum` as a variable name, although if you're going to use it then I suppose an exercise in which you're not permitted to call the builtin `sum` is as good a time as any :-)

Comment: @SteveJessop - thanks. Made it `mySum`...